# How to store index number of row, based on other column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to store order in which rows were written, but new for every unique value in other column

For example:

| Column A | Base | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 |

So "index" must store identity based on "Base"

I tried:

`INSERT INTO mytable ("Column A", "Base", "index") VALUES ($1, $2, next_index($2))`

Where next_index:

```
Declare
new_index bigint;
BEGIN
SELECT MAX(index) + 1
INTO new_index
FROM mytable
WHERE Base = *arg*;
RETURN new_index;
END;
```

But this doesn't work, when i make concurrent inserts: next_index() were counted multiple times before insert was made, so value of indexes were the same for this rows, but they must be unique for specific Base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Jens. Storing when the row was written should be done with a timestamp.

That said, to achieve the results in your example, you could use row_number.

```
  SELECT Column_A
       , Base
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Base ORDER BY Column_A) as _index
    FROM temp
ORDER BY Column_A, _index
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hESvgOlZ)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to store a timestamp and create the index in a view.

An alternative would be to prevent concurrent inserts by requiring a lock.
The problem here is that all applications doing inserts have to honor that which becomes a organisational problem.

Or you could achieve something similar by creating a unique index based on `Base` and `index`. When two concurrent inserts happen, the one will get a unique key violation and would have to retry.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered the structure *max(x)+1* when used in a multi-user environment is virtually guaranteed to produce duplicates. One way to avoid this basically ignores the *index* on insert, just use a sequence. Then for selection create a view, that constructs the order index from the relative values stored. ([Demo here)](https://dbfiddle.uk/EIR5zTkI)

```
create table test_tbl(column_A integer 
                , base     integer
                , gindex   serial 
                );

create or replace view test as
  select Column_a "Column A"
       , Base     "Base" 
       , gindex   "Stored Index"
       , row_number(*) over (partition by base order by gindex) "Index"
    from test_tbl;
```

Potential downside. You have to manage the column `gindex` for Updates and Deletes. But I guess you need to do essentially the same maintenance either anyway.

But, I also agree with Jens. Just use a timestamp.